# Chinese characters displays in Firefox on some sites

Tags: firefox, chinese

I just opened Firefox and all of a sudden some sites have started showing Chinese characters. Refresh doesn't seem to help. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Here's the screenshot:

[image: shot of DiveIntoHTML5]

It's showing the same way in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web site http://diveintohtml5.com (currently) appears to show a partial Chinese translation of the book, just like your screenshot.

I don't think this is a problem you can fix.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools->Options->Content tab.  Check your default font, then click Advanced on the Default Fone line and make sure you default encoding is correct (mine is Western ISO-88591-1).

Finally, and this may be whats messed up: in the Content tab at the bottom there is a Language section. Click the Choose button and make sure English/United States [en-us] is first. (or w/e your country is)

Comment: Did what you told. Everything was its default value. Didn't help. Any other way?